# How to put nodes into parent node?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I would like to add a parent node with attribute and put nodes inside of this parent node. I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <row>
      <PHONE_NUM>124</PHONE_NUM>
      <PHONE_ORDER>1</PHONE_ORDER>      
   </row>
   <row>
      <PHONE_NUM>123</PHONE_NUM>
      <PHONE_ORDER>2</PHONE_ORDER>      
   </row>
   <row>
      <PHONE_NUM>181</PHONE_NUM>
      <PHONE_ORDER>3</PHONE_ORDER>      
   </row>   
</foo>
```

I've tried this approach:

```
var xmlString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
    <foo>
       <row>
          <PHONE_NUM>124</PHONE_NUM>
          <PHONE_ORDER>1</PHONE_ORDER>      
       </row>
       <row>
          <PHONE_NUM>123</PHONE_NUM>
          <PHONE_ORDER>2</PHONE_ORDER>      
       </row>
       <row>
          <PHONE_NUM>181</PHONE_NUM>
          <PHONE_ORDER>3</PHONE_ORDER>      
       </row>   
    </foo>";

var report = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var newdoc = new XDocument();
newdoc.Add(new XElement("testsuites")); 
newdoc.Root.Add(report.Root);
```

But the above code generates is withoud `id` and order `books` has become a root :

```
<books>
  <foo>
      <row>
          <PHONE_NUM>124</PHONE_NUM> 
          <PHONE_ORDER>1</PHONE_ORDER> 
      </row>
      <row>
          <PHONE_NUM>123</PHONE_NUM> 
          <PHONE_ORDER>2</PHONE_ORDER> 
      </row>
      <row>
          <PHONE_NUM>181</PHONE_NUM> 
          <PHONE_ORDER>3</PHONE_ORDER> 
      </row>
      </foo>
  </books>
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<foo>
    <books id=""1"">
       <row>
          <PHONE_NUM>124</PHONE_NUM>
          <PHONE_ORDER>1</PHONE_ORDER>      
       </row>
       <row>
          <PHONE_NUM>123</PHONE_NUM>
          <PHONE_ORDER>2</PHONE_ORDER>      
       </row>
       <row>
          <PHONE_NUM>181</PHONE_NUM>
          <PHONE_ORDER>3</PHONE_ORDER>      
       </row>  
    </books>
</foo>
```

If it is possible, it would be great if `XmlDocument` class will be used. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process helps you create a new child and move all nodes under this new child.

1. create a new element first..
2. Move all the nodes under this new element
3. Add the new element where you needed in the XML.

```
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
doc2.LoadXml(xmlString);

var newElement = doc2.CreateElement("body");
newElement.SetAttribute("id", "1");

var moveNodes = doc2.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//row");
foreach(XmlNode node in moveNodes)
    newElement.AppendChild(node);

doc2.GetElementsByTagName("foo")[0].AppendChild(newElement);
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <body id="1">
        <row>
            <PHONE_NUM>124</PHONE_NUM>
            <PHONE_ORDER>1</PHONE_ORDER>
        </row>
        <row>
            <PHONE_NUM>123</PHONE_NUM>
            <PHONE_ORDER>2</PHONE_ORDER>
        </row>
        <row>
            <PHONE_NUM>181</PHONE_NUM>
            <PHONE_ORDER>3</PHONE_ORDER>
        </row>
    </body>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's about what you want to do, using the `XDocument` class. It's simply a matter of creating new nodes and modifying existing nodes with your specification:

```
var report = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
report.Root.Name = XName.Get("books", report.Root.Name.NamespaceName);
report.Root.Add(new XAttribute("id", 1));
var newDoc = new XDocument();
var newRoot = new XElement("foo");
newRoot.Add(report.Root);
newDoc.Add(newRoot);
```